# Why do I need to convert impedance to admittance in this problem

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance

1 = 18 A, 2 = 15 A ,  = 30 A and R2 = 4 Ω.
determine 1 and L .

This is the picture of the circuit:

[image: Image 1]

And this my solution all the way to the point where I have uncertainties:

[image: Image 2]

Now I can solve this in two ways:

1. I can solve it without converting impedance to admittance (gives the wrong answer)
2. Or I can solve it with converting impedance to admittance (gives the correct answer)

[image: Image 3]

My question is why will I get the wrong answer when not converting impedance into admittance, it seems mathematically correct, but it is the wrong solution, can someone explain?

Comment: Can you try re-writing your attempted solution(s) in MathJax? Trying to read your faded pencil marks is making it more trouble than necessary to try to understand your problem.

Comment: Yeah. Some of your 9s look exactly like 4s as well. I managed to get through it but half my time was spent trying to read the writing.

Comment: Ok, im gonna try to fix that, is there any tutorial on how to write in MathJax?

Comment: It's too bad you don't have high enough permissions to try and edit my answer so you can view the mathjax code. I pretty much used everything you need to use normally. \$ to start and stop. {} to group command arguments together, and each command is preceded by a \. Common commands are \times, \frac{}{}, \sqrt{}, \angle{}. Use your preview when you type. It will let you know whether you did it right or not. Underscore for subscripts: X_L or X_{L}. The {} is used if your subscript is multiple characters.

Comment: Can you send me code , I don't know if you can send messages on stackExchange

Comment: I just wrote it out everything you need to know. It's easy. You have a preview that you can use as a syntax checker. ^ for superscript. ^{} for more than one superscript as per the {} for grouping arguments I mentioned.

Comment: I will try to do that tomorrow ,can just tell me how to insert images like you did and how to do power of some symbol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two things at work here:

### 1. You are not taking into account that \$R_1\$ and \$X_L\$ are in parallel and not in series.

When you write \$ Z_1 = R_1 + X_L \$, you are stating that they are in series, not in parallel.

The lumped impedance of \$Z_1\$ does have a form:
\$Z_1 = Re(Z_1) + Im(Z_1)j\$

But these real and imaginary terms are not \$R_1\$ or \$X_L\$

You should have written \$ Z_1 = R_1 || jX_L \$ and expanded that out. Then your math will accurately reflect that they are in parallel. The real terms in this expanded expression will be \$R_1\$ and the imaginary terms will be \$X_L\$.

### 2. You cannot just invert the real and imaginary components of a complex impedance/admittance to find the admittance/impedance.

For example:

\$ Z = 2 \angle{45} = \sqrt{2} + j\sqrt{2}\$

\$ Y = \frac{1}{Z} = \frac{1}{2}\angle{-45} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} - j\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \$

We agree on those right?

But then in your second solution, you try and calculate Y by individually finding the reciprocal of the real and imaginary components of Z:

\$Y_{wrong}  = \frac{1}{Re(Z)} + j\frac{1}{Im(Z)} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + j\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$

Or maybe:

\$Y_{wrong}  = \frac{1}{Re(Z)} + \frac{1}{Im(Z)j} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - j\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$

if you thought that the \$j\$ should be included in the reciprocal.

You might start feeling that something is wrong and doesn't make sense here because it's inconsistent. Look at the \$j\$. It only makes sense that you would have to include it as part of the reciprocal so it ends up in the denominator (or in the numerator as a \$-j\$)...but at the same time, if you do that then it's obviously wrong since there is an inductance, not a capacitance so \$-j\$ is obviously wrong. It doesn't feel right both ways and that's because it is wrong.

Either way, obviously \$Y \ne Y_{wrong}\$ so it does not work. It does not work because the real and imaginary components are tied together and so you can't just break them apart and invert them individually.

**Here's an interesting exercise:** What happens if you try to find the admittance of a resistor \$R\$ by doing what you tried to do, except now think of it as \$ R + 0j \$?

You get a divide by zero! We both know that in the end you do get \$ Y = \frac{1}{R}\$ but math to actually get there is is different. The reciprocal of a the singular component (real or imaginary, as long as there is only one) is just a shortcut that only works in that circumstance. It cannot be applied to complex numbers in general.

So I think your second solution is wrong too. You just happened to accidentally account for the parallel \$ R_1\$ and \$X_L \$ when you incorrectly tried to calculate Y by individually inverting the real and imaginary components of Z.

Comment: Thank you! that makes sense I should've used Xp= U<0 / I <-49.46 -> 1 / R + 1 / X_L = ( 2.17 + 2.53j) ^-1 and then I should was supposed to do 1 / R =0.195 
and 1 / xl  = - 0.223 j I's that correct

Comment: Note that the reason you get the correct answer by reciprocating the \$R_1\$ and \$X_L\$ is that they are individual components with only a real or imaginary part, not both. If you tried to do that with the lump sum impedance \$Z_1\$, your answer would be wrong. So be wary when changing admittance to impedance. If it has both real and imaginary parts, change to phasor form and invert it there.

Comment: Ok i will thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cannot possibly be 15 A, 18 A and 30 A - that would require \$\small I_1\$ and \$\small I_2\$ to be out of phase by \$\small 147^o\$, which is not possible. Maximum phase angle between these is \$\small <90^o\$.